# Bilinear map on the set of finite sequences

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, continuity

Let $X = \{ x = (x_n)_{n=1} ^ {\infty}\subset \mathbb{R} \ \ | \ \ \exists N \in \mathbb{N} : \forall n>N : x_n=0 \}$

Let the norm on $X$ be $||x|| = \sum _{n=1} ^{\infty} |x_n|$ (which is fine, because the sequences have only finitely many nonzero terms).

Given $a = (a_n) _{n=1} ^{\infty}$ we define a bilinear map:

$B : X \times X \ni (x,y) \rightarrow \sum_{n=1} ^{\infty} a_nx_ny_n \in \mathbb{R}$

Prove that $B(x, \cdot)$ is continuous for any $x \in X$.

What is the necessary and sufficient condition for $B$ to be continuous?

For $u,w \in X :||u - w|| < \delta$ we have: $\sum _{n=1} ^{\infty} |u_n-w_n|< \delta$

$|B(x, u) - B(x, w)| = |\sum _1 ^{\infty} a_nx_n(u_n-w_n)| \le \sum _1 ^{\infty} |a_nx_n(u_n-w_n)| \le \max \{a_nx_n \ | n \in \mathbb{N} \} \cdot \delta < \epsilon$

if for any given $\epsilon$ we take $\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{\max...}$
Isn't this approach a bit naive. It seems to me that since there are only finitely many nonzero terms in every sequence in $X$ we can choose such a maximum product $a_nx_n$.

Could you tell me if I'm right and help me with the rest?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first part, the continuity of $B(x,\,\cdot\,)$ for any fixed $x$, you have exactly the right approach, only you forgot to take the absolute value in the maximum. You can't really do anything else, there are sequences $u \in X$ with

$$\lvert B(x,u)\rvert = \lVert u\rVert\cdot \max \{ \lvert a_n x_n\rvert : n \in \mathbb{N}\},$$

and thus by linearity, you have for all $u\in X$

$$\sup \left\{\lvert B(x,w) - B(x,u)\rvert : \lVert w-u\rVert < \delta \right\} = \delta\cdot \max \{ \lvert a_n x_n\rvert : n \in \mathbb{N}\}.$$

Choosing $\delta = \varepsilon/\max \{ \lvert a_n x_n\rvert : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ hence works for all $u$, and for no $u$ there is a larger choice that works.

> Isn't this approach a bit naive.

No. It's the straightforward and correct (after taking absolute values) approach. The (bi)linearity ensures that there are no hidden traps that would make anything more complicated necessary.

> It seems to me that since there are only finitely many nonzero terms in every sequence in $X$ we can choose such a maximum product $a_nx_n$.

Right. Since there are only finitely many nonzero terms, the maximum exists. If there were infinitely many nonzero terms, you would need to replace the maximum with a supremum, and a necessary condition on the sequence $(a_n)$ for $B(x,\,\cdot\,)$ to be continuous would then be that $\sup \{ \lvert a_nx_n\rvert : n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is finite. That would not be satisfied for every sequence $(a_n)$ and all $(x_n)$ with $\sum \lvert x_n\rvert < \infty$.

For the joint continuity in both variables, let us first look at what is needed for $B$ to be continuous in $(0,0)$. Given any $\varepsilon > 0$, there must be a neighbourhood $U$ of $(0,0)$ such that $\lvert B(x,y)\rvert \leqslant \varepsilon$ for all $(x,y) \in U$. A neighbourhood of $(0,0)$ is by definition a set that contains the product of two open balls, each centered at $0$, so there must be $\delta_1,\delta_2 > 0$ such that $\lVert x\rVert < \delta_1,\, \lVert y\rVert < \delta_2 \Rightarrow \lvert B(x,y)\rvert < \varepsilon$.

By bilinearity, we then have for $\lVert\xi\rVert < 1,\,\lVert\eta\rVert < 1$

$$\lvert B(\xi,\eta)\rvert = \left\lvert B\left(\frac{\delta_1\xi}{\delta_1},\frac{\delta_2\eta}{\delta_2}\right)\right\rvert = \frac{1}{\delta_1\delta_2}\lvert B(\delta_1\xi,\delta_2\eta)\rvert < \frac{\varepsilon}{\delta_1\delta_2},$$

since $\lVert\delta_1\xi\rVert < \delta_1$ and $\lVert \delta_2\eta\rVert < \delta_2$.

Thus if $B \colon X\times X\to \mathbb{R}$

is continuous in $(0,0)$, we have

$$\lVert B\rVert := \sup \left\{\lvert B(x,y)\rvert : \lVert x\rVert < 1,\, \lVert y\rVert < 1\right\} < \infty.$$

If that condition is fulfilled, then bilinearity gives the estimate

$$\lvert B(x,y)\rvert \leqslant \lVert B\rVert\cdot\lVert x\rVert\,\lVert y\rVert$$

for all $x,y\in X$. Now you can use that estimate and

$$B(x,y) - B(x_0,y_0) = B(x_0,y-y_0) + B(x-x_0,y_0) + B(x-x_0,y-y_0)$$

to deduce the continuity of $B$ in an arbitrary $(x_0,y_0) \in X\times X$.

So $B$ is continuous if and only if

$$\sup \left\{\lvert B(x,y)\rvert : \lVert x\rVert < 1,\, \lVert y\rVert < 1\right\} < \infty.\tag{1}$$

Now find the condition on the sequence $(a_n)$ that ensures $(1)$.